# Which kind of servers are for VueJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I know VueJS is a side server rendering (SSR) technology, so, which servers are for this framework? Can you give some examples?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. Your question is off topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a lot of things mixed up, so I strongly suggest you go through the entire documentation. VueJS is a client-side application framework, like React, Ember, Backbone, etc.

Server-Side Rendering is just one of the features that VueJS comes with, which basically means that a server will pre-generate the HTML with the data prepopulated instead of making the user fetch all its parts and assemble them in the browser (which is way slower, and way worse for SEO). If by "what kind of server" you mean what type of language the SSR compilation runs in, it's Node.JS.

Good luck! There's a lot of terminology.